# Python Requests-Cache still querying remote URL

Tags: python, caching, python-requests

I'm using the [Requests-Cache](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/) library to cache results from [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). It appears to install a cache just fine; requesting a URL creates a `.sqlite` cache file, and subsequent requests retrieve that data, even if the remote page changes.

My internet connection is rather poor today, and I noticed my script (which makes many (supposedly cached) requests) was running slowly. As a quick sanity check, I tried a test script to make a cache, then ran it again after disconnecting my computer from wifi. However, this errors out:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='magicplugin.normalitycomics.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /update/updatelist.txt (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x110390d68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

Why is the request even trying to connect to the remote site, if Requests-Cache is redirecting it to use the local cached data? Is there a way to avoid this? I don't need to slow down my script (particularly if my connection is poor) and make unnecessary requests from the server.

Comment: Are you sure that particular request is cached? what's the lifespan of the cache?

Comment: please shows us the code you're using to create the cache and for requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out!

My actual code makes requests that sometimes successfully get pages, and sometimes get a 404.

The only reason my simple test script replicated the problem was that I made a typo in the page I was requesting. Requests received a 404. Even though Requests-Cache created a cache file, it did not store this result in it.

It turns out that by default, Requests-Cache [only caches 200-code responses, but this is configurable](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.3/user_guide.html?highlight=allowable_codes#status-codes):

```
requests_cache.install_cache('example_cache', allowable_codes=(200, 404))
```

And now it works fine!